# Compile Error: Only top-level class variables can be declared static

Tags: apex, unit-test, compile-error

```
@isTest
private class TestRejectDoubleBooking{
    public void TestSingleBooking(){
      static testmethod void TestSingleBooking() {
    Datetime now = System.now();

    Speaker__c speaker = new Speaker__c(First_Name__c='John', Last_Name__c='Smith');
    insert speaker;

    Session__c session = new Session__c(Name='Some Session', Session_Date__c=now);
    insert session;

    Session_Speaker__c assignment =
    new Session_Speaker__c(Session__c=session.Id, Speaker__c=speaker.Id);

    Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(assignment, false);

    System.assert(result.isSuccess());
}   
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Your question looks like a message that you are getting compile error. Can you please specific on what problem you are facing or what is your doubt/question. Please go through [ask] section to understand how to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a method within a method. Remove this line:

```
public void TestSingleBooking() {
```

And also remove the corresponding closing bracket `}`.

**Correct Code:**

```
@IsTest
class TestRejectDoubleBooking
{
    static testMethod void testSingleBooking()
    {
        // test code here
    }
}
```

What you are doing instead is trying to declare a method within a method, as stated above. Note also that your methods must be declared `testmethod` or annotated with `@IsTest` in order to actually *run*.

**Incorrect Code:**

```
@IsTest
class TestRejectDoubleBooking
{
    public void testSingleBooking()
    {
        static testMethod void testSingleBooking()
        {
            // test code here
        }
    }
}
```

I also find that careful, consistent use of indentation can make these types of problems much more clear.